# Find file with certain extension and open the file in a program using a batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory

I'm trying to search for a file that ends with *.ac and open that file in a program.
There will always just be one file with this extension.
The directory where the bat file will search is always the directory where it's running from.

Currently this works:

```
@echo off
for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="myFileName.ac" set p=%%~dpnxa
start /d "C:\Program Files (86)\CaseWare\" cwin32.exe "%p%"
```

But the myFileName.ac will always have a different name.

I tried to change it to *.ac but then it doesn't work :(

```
@echo off
for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="*.ac" set p=%%~dpnxa
start /d "C:\Program Files (86)\CaseWare\" cwin32.exe "%p%"
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*.ac) do set p=%%~dpnxa
```

should find that elusive file.

```
@echo off
for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*.ac) do start /d "C:\Program Files (86)\CaseWare\" cwin32.exe "%%~dpnxa"
```

should process it.